# How do I configure Pylint with VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

For my setup, I have Pylint ==3.0.0a4 and VSCode Version: 1.67.2. In my VSCode settings.json, I have

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
```

and every time I save a .py file, VSCode runs the following command:

```
~/.local/share/virtualenvs/hello-world-n4ICiflw/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.6.2/pythonFiles/linter.py -m pylint ~/code/hello-world/src/main.py
```

which I believe is VSCode running the Python linter via a proxy call to `linter.py -m pylint` using `--output-format=json` by default, but it fails with the following error

```
##########Linting Output - pylint##########


[ERROR 2022-4-30 15:11:59.266]: Linter 'pylint' failed to parse the output '. [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at s.parseMessages (/Users/kevinyang/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.6.2/out/client/extension.js:2:518074)
    at s.run (/Users/kevinyang/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.6.2/out/client/extension.js:2:499508)
    at async s.runLinter (/Users/kevinyang/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.6.2/out/client/extension.js:2:517589)]
```

It appears as though the `linter.py` cannot handle the JSON output produced by pylint.

I also tried installing the Pylint Extension, but ran into the same problem.

Running `$ pylint src/main.py` manually on a shell works just fine.

Has anybody else come across this problem and solved it?

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by downgrading pylint to ==2.13.4. Seems like it's a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18802) in recent versions of Pylint.

Comment: The version shouldn't be an issue anymore. I was using `pylint 2.15.5` successfully with vscode.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem in my case:**

Incorrect pylintrc file path configuration.

**Troubleshooting**:

1. Look at Output->Python logs
2. Try running the pylint command that is being used there:

   pylint --rcfile=~/projects/../my_project/pylintrc  ~/projects/../my_project/a_script_to_analyze.py
3. See the error (which is not a Json object, that's why you are getting this weird Json error):

"*The config file /home/../my_projects/.pylintrc doesn't exist!*"

**Solution in my case:**
Modify your workspace settings to use a valid pylintrc file

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
            "--rcfile=${workspaceFolder}/pylintrc"
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the vscode setting for `python.linting.pylintPath`. I was using Git Bash for Windows, and had `python.linting.pylintPath` incorrectly set to `/c/Python39/Scripts/pylint`. It didn't like the forward slashes.

I had to change it to `c:\Python39\Scripts\pylint`. Or better yet, just leave the setting blank. vscode should be able to find the correct version itself.

Look at the vscode Output > Python window to see the error messages.